# Multi replacement in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have XML as like below:

```
    <w:body>
   <w:p>
    <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
     </w:pPr>
  <w:r><w:t>1274394 The milk costs , $1.99 [12] test Figure 1</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
 <w:p>
  <w:pPr>
  <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r><w:t>sample text Figure 1 and [1]</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
</w:body>
```

I would like to get an output like below with XSLT:

```
<w:body>
 <w:p>
  <w:pPr>
     <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r><w:t>1274394 The milk costs , $1.99 <ref>[12]</ref> test <fig>Figure 1</fig></w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
  <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
  </w:pPr>
 <w:r><w:t>sample text <fig>Figure 1</fig> and <ref>[1]</ref></w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
</w:body>
```

My XSLT is:

```
<xsl:template match="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val='paragraph']//text()">
<xsl:param name="figregex">
  <xsl:text>(Figure)\p{Zs}([0-9]{1,2})</xsl:text>
</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="matchedRegex">
  <xsl:text>(\[)([0-9]{1,2})(\])</xsl:text>
</xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="fig-first" select="&quot;&lt;fig&gt;&quot;"/>
<xsl:variable name="fig-sec" select="&quot;&lt;/fig&gt;&quot;"/>
<xsl:variable name="r-first" select="&quot;&lt;ref&gt;&quot;"/>
<xsl:variable name="r-sec" select="&quot;&lt;/ref&gt;&quot;"/>
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$matchedRegex} | {$figregex} ">
<xsl:matching-substring>
<xsl:if test="matches(., $figregex)" >
    <xsl:value-of select="$fig-first" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$fig-sec" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="matches(., $matchedRegex)" >
    <xsl:value-of select="$r-first" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$r-sec" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
```

Its working fine but if both present in the same line one in front is first getting converted. Can anyone help me on this? The output which I am getting is:

```
<w:body>
 <w:p>
  <w:pPr>
     <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r><w:t>1274394 The milk costs , $1.99 <ref>[12] </ref>test Figure 1</w:t></w:r>
 </w:p>
 <w:p>
  <w:pPr>
  <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r><w:t>sample text<fig> Figure 1 </fig>and [1]</w:t></w:r>
  </w:p>
 </w:body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 Style-sheet ...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:w="www"
  exclude-result-prefixes='xsl fn'>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
      
<xsl:template match="w:t/text()">
 <xsl:variable name="phase1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="fig" />
 </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$phase1" mode="ref" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="text()" mode="fig">
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="Figure (\d{{1,2}})">
 <xsl:matching-substring>
  <fig>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </fig>
 </xsl:matching-substring>
 <xsl:non-matching-substring>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:non-matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="ref">
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\[(\d{{1,2}})\]">
 <xsl:matching-substring>
  <ref>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </ref>
 </xsl:matching-substring>
 <xsl:non-matching-substring>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:non-matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="ref">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="ref"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
          
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...will transform the sample input into...**

```
<w:body xmlns:w="www">
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>1274394 The milk costs , $1.99 <ref>[12]</ref> test <fig>Figure 1</fig>
         </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="paragraph"/>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>sample text <fig>Figure 1</fig> and <ref>[1]</ref>
         </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
```

### Notes

1. This style-sheet uses a pipe-line design. The first stage ('fig') processes the Figure pattern, and the second stage ('ref') processes the ref pattern.
2. This is not the only good solution. It would be quiet viable, and perhaps even tighter, to use a common named template instead of a ref and fig mode templates. Some other Stackie might like to rise to the challenge and show a simpler one-pass solution.
3. Try not to use disable-output-escaping unless you really need it. In doing so, you discard a lot of the power of XSLT. It is analogous to using an SQL expression to generate a data-set, but then use some assembler code to compute one of the column outputs.
4. When using a literal regex, remember to double-escape the curlies.

Comment: Thanks. Its working..., but if i want to add one more replacement ie for table, <tab>Table 1</tab>, how to include this in `<xsl:template match="w:t/text()"> <xsl:variable name="phase1"> <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="fig" /> </xsl:variable> <xsl:apply-templates select="$phase1" mode="ref" /> </xsl:template>` if i add `<xsl:apply-templates select="$phase1" mode="tab" />` I am not getting the result.

Comment: Add a third phase. You need a variable for phase2. But if you have 3 phases, more-or-less operating the same way, it might be time to switch to a parametrised template technique.

Comment: Post another question, if you need a more generic solution to a more generic problem. For example, if all the patterns and encapsulating tags are in a look-up table of arbitary length.

Comment: <xsl:variable name="phase2">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="tab"/>
     </xsl:variable>
If I use the above variable phase2, getting the same problem which I faced earlier that getting output two times..., Your help greatly appreciated

Comment: Ask a new question and properly format it. I can't read code in comments.